# In Core vs On Chain Security

Tags: security

In this rfc: [CoreJam](https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/RFCs/blob/gav-corejam/text/corejam.md) Gav mentions workloads being done on-chain vs in-core. I was wondering what the security differences are between work done in these two spheres. Is there a difference? Thank you.